# Adding new structure items to top of structure

Tags: structure

Is there a way to add new items in a structure to the top of the list? Now I have to drag it from the bottom to the top.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware there is nothing like that natively to Craft. You can either:

1. Submit a [Feature Request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests) for adding pages to the top of structures
2. Develop your own [Craft plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up) that provides this functionality

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 
Found this request: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7205061-setting-to-append-or-prepend-new-structure-entries

Comment: @sethne Looks like John is one step ahead!

Comment: Feature request migrated to https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/870